# Set Spring Boot backend timeout to indefinitely

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, session-timeout

To give some context, I'm building a PWA (Progressive Web App) for myself and some friends as a test project. I'm using basic authentication.

As it is a PWA I want it to behave like other apps do, which includes not having to log in every few days keeping the user logged in. Disabling the timeout may not be the best way as it gives security risks but for now it should do just fine.

I already tried to increase the timeout setting to a high number and use the -1 value like below.

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=9999999999
spring.session.timeout=9999999999
```

and

```
server.servlet.session.timeout=-1
spring.session.timeout=-1
```

But both do not work.

This is how I configured my security:

```
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .headers().cacheControl().disable().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/user").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/*").authenticated()
            .anyRequest().permitAll()
        .and()
            .cors()
        .and()
            .csrf()
                .ignoringAntMatchers("/logout")
                .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse())
        .and()
            .httpBasic()
        .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
                .clearAuthentication(true);
    }
```

As mentioned, after a few days the application will still timeout and give me an 401 error (even though the cookies still exists) which means the user has to log in again.

Does anyone know how I can make the session really long or indefinitely. And if this is not possible which other solution could I use to solve this problem?

Comment: You should make your backend statless and not use the session at all. Instead use a token security mechanism.

Comment: Thank you I will look into making the backend stateless

Comment: Would you mind if I add my comment as the answer that you can accept it?

Comment: Yes, when I tried it out I will do an update if and how it worked out